# Computing table name from model name

Tags: cakephp

In my CakePHP application, I have a model like this:

```
class Duck extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Duck';

    function get_table_name() {
        $tbl_name = //compute default table name for this model         
    }
}
```

I would like to write the function `get_table_name()` that outputs the default table name for the model. For the example above, it should output `ducks`.

**EDIT:**
Several people have pointed out the use of `$this->table`.
I did small testing and found out the following:

1. In the question as I have put above, `$this->table` indeed contains the table name.
2. However, actually, my code looked more like this:

   ```
   class Duck extends Bird {
       var $name = 'Duck';
       function get_table_name(){
           $tbl_name = //comput default table name for this model
       }
   }
   class Bird extends AppModel {

   }
   ```

   In this case $this->table is empty string.
   I went with this approach because I wanted to share some code between two of my models. Looks like this is not a good way to share code between models which need some common functionality.

Comment: if you want to share code between models, you can either connect them through relationship, or put the code in app_model

Comment: If you didn't want the model code to be applied to all models you can also just make a [`Model` behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1071/Behaviors) and assign it to the appropriate models as necessary.

Comment: Note: CakePHP behaviors are [mixins](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Mixin) (allowing multiple inheritance). Extending only gets you single inheritance (as you can only have one super class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the name of the table that the model is currently using, you can use: `$this->table`.  If you don't manually change the model's table conventions, this may be the most useful in the case of CakePHP ever changing its conventions to use table names using something other than Inflector.

Comment: I just checked, `$this->table` is empty string in my case.

Comment: This is the better way.  imo not because you might break a future version of cake but accessing a property should be faster than having to invoke an entire method.  **Edit** _Except for the fact that it doesn't work apparently._

Comment: It works alright, provided my model inherits directly from `AppModel`. See the edit in the original question for details.

Comment: Do you need to use the table name in a raw query? If so, you will not to get the entire name together with table prefix: $this->getDataSource()->fullTableName($this)

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the [`Inflector`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1478/Inflector) class.

```
Inflector::tableize($this->name)
```

*(`tableize` calls two Inflector methods to generate the table name: [underscore()](http://api.cakephp.org/class/inflector#method-Inflectorunderscore) and [pluralize()](http://api.cakephp.org/class/inflector#method-Inflectorpluralize))*

**Edit:**

According to [the source code](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/1.3/cake/libs/model/model.php#L479), `$this->table` *should* contain the name of the table that CakePHP will use for the model, but in my experience this isn't always set. I'm not sure why.

Comment: This is helpful. I was wondering if the pluralized name is already stored somewhere (just as `$this->name` stores the table name). I tried printing `$this` (from the model), but that did not help. So, inflector is the way to go I guess.

Comment: For me, `$this->table` is an empty string. I was thinking it gets set only if you set table name of a model to non default name.

Comment: $this->useTable should be used, but Inflector method is good if you want to manually get table name

Answer (score 1):

[CakePHP's `Inflector`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1479/Class-methods)

```
function get_table_name() {

    $tbl_name = Inflector::pluralize($this->name);

}
```

OR the [`tableize`](http://api13.cakephp.org/class/inflector#method-Inflectortableize) method

```
function get_table_name() {

    $tbl_name = Inflector::tableize($this->name);

}
```

**Edit**

This also addresses the apparent "ghost" issue with `$this->table` in the Model.

[Digging around in the `__construct` for `Model`](http://api13.cakephp.org/view_source/model/#line-403) I discovered two things:

1. Cake uses `Inflector::tableize()` to get the table name.  **This alone** is enough to warrant using `tableize` over `pluralize`.  You'll get consistent results.
2. `$this->table` is not set by the `Model::__construct()` unless `$this->useTable === false` AND `$this->table === false`.

It appears that if you know you haven't set `$this->useTable` to `false` you should be able to use this over `$this->table`.  Admittedly though I only briefly scanned the source and I haven't really dug deep enough to say why `$this->table` isn't working sometimes.

Comment: aah...`tableize` certainly feels better than generic `pluralize`.

Comment: @VivekPandey I agree, `pluralize` does feel way more "dirty" now that I've discovered the `tableize` method.  I would definitely use that as it may be doing some other stuff to achieve the result.

Comment: @Charles: it does, but it only matters if you use multiple-word tables: [see source](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/1.3/cake/libs/inflector.php#L544).

Comment: It may only matter in multiple-word tables but I'd still say for OP using `Inflector::pluralize` would constitute a code smell since we know for a fact there's a specific, purpose-built function.

Answer (score 1):

To get the full table name for a model you have to take the table prefix into account.

```
$table = empty($this->table) ? Inflector::tableize($this->name) : $this->table;
$fullTableName = $this->tablePrefix . $table;
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to use inflector to get the table name from model's name

```
$tableName = Inflector::pluralize(Inflector::underscore($model));
```

but this is not really universal, using `useTable` looks better, by default it will contain table's name by convention, and if you have a table that does not match the conventions, then you should manually specify it by `useTable`. So, in both cases the result will be correct

```
$this->User->useTable
```